# Conditional List comprehension for tuples when length more than one

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a sentence with tuples which indicate the positions of where there is either a country or a number:

```
sample = In the first 11 months of 2004 Hong Kong 's international airport at Chek Lap Kok handled daily an average of 592 flights , 92,630 passengers , and more than 7,734 tons of cargo.
```

And then:

```
tokenIDs2number = {(22,): 592.00, (25,): 92630.00,(34,): 7734.00}
tokenIDs2location = {(8,9): Hong Kong}
```

I need to for different combinations of these tuples, create various combinations of sentences which I call slot sentences:

```
In the first 11 months of 2004 LOCATION_SLOT 's international airport at Chek Lap Kok handled daily an average of NUMBER_SLOT flights , 92,630 passengers , and more than 7,734 tons of cargo.

In the first 11 months of 2004 LOCATION_SLOT 's international airport at Chek Lap Kok handled daily an average of 592 flights , NUMBER_SLOT passengers , and more than 7,734 tons of cargo.

In the first 11 months of 2004 LOCATION_SLOT 's international airport at Chek Lap Kok handled daily an average of 592 flights , 92,630 passengers , and more than NUMBER_SLOT tons of cargo.
```

However, my current code essentially takes combinations of the elements within the tuples, so I have two sentences like:

```
In the first 11 months of 2004 LOCATION_SLOT Kong 's international airport at Chek Lap Kok handled daily an average of NUMBER_SLOT flights , 92,630 passengers , and more than 7,734 tons of cargo.

In the first 11 months of 2004 Hong LOCATION_SLOT 's international airport at Chek Lap Kok handled daily an average of NUMBER_SLOT flights , 92,630 passengers , and more than 7,734 tons of cargo.
```

As an example.

How do I solve this so that when I have a tuple key of `len>1`, I fill in all slots in that key as one LOCATION or NUMBER slot as per my desire?

Current code:

```
 for locationTokenIDs, location in tokenIDs2location.items():
                    for numberTokenIDs, number in tokenIDs2number.items():    
                        sentenceDict = {}    
                        sentenceDict["sentence"] = sample    
                        sentenceDict["location-value-pair"] = {location:number}  
                        for locationTokenID in locationTokenIDs:
                            for numberTokenID in numberTokenIDs:                                   
                                finalTokens = cleanSample.split()
                                finalTokens[numberTokenID] = "NUMBER_SLOT"
                                finalTokens[locationTokenID] = "LOCATION_SLOT"   
                                slotSentence = (" ").join(finalTokens)
                                sentenceDict["parsedSentence"] = slotSentence
```

Note, I have to create a dictionary that also keeps track of the location-value pair and the original sentence for each slot sentence combination . The key part is generating the right `slotSentence`.

Note this is only one example, the numbers may even be `24000000` where the value in the sentence was `24 million`, same trillion, million, billion and thousand.

**If this is impossible, one other option would be to fill in all slots in the combination**:

```
In the first 11 months of 2004 LOCATION_SLOT LOCATION_SLOT 's international airport at Chek Lap Kok handled daily an average of NUMBER_SLOT flights , 92,630 passengers , and more than 7,734 tons of cargo.
```

**And then perhaps adapt the sentence to remove consecutive slots, but my preference would be to do everything in one shot.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my use case but using a roundabout way.

I first allow for slot sentences which contain multiple `LOCATION_SLOT` or `NUMBER_SLOT` - if one tuple in the combo contains 2 or more slots, I fill in all:

```
sentences2location2values = []

for locationTokenIDs, location in tokenIDs2location.items():
                    for numberTokenIDs, number in tokenIDs2number.items():    
                        sentenceDict = {}    
                        sentenceDict["sentence"] = sample    
                        sentenceDict["location-value-pair"] = {location:number}  
                        for locationTokenID in locationTokenIDs:
                            sampleTokens[locationTokenID] = "LOCATION_SLOT"

                        for numberTokenID in numberTokenIDs:
                            sampleTokens[numberTokenID] = "NUMBER_SLOT"

                    slotSentence = (" ").join(sampleTokens)
                    sentenceDict["parsedSentence"] = slotSentence
                    sentences2location2values.append(sentenceDict)
```

Then, I change the parsed sentences to remove consecutive location and number slots:

```
for i,sentence in enumerate(sentences2location2values):
        sampleTokens = sentence['parsedSentence'].split()
        newTokens = []
        for i,token in enumerate(sampleTokens):
            if i>0 and ((token == "LOCATION_SLOT" and sampleTokens[i-1]=="LOCATION_SLOT") or (token == "NUMBER_SLOT" and sampleTokens[i-1]=="NUMBER_SLOT")):
                continue
            else:
                newTokens.append(token)

        sentence['parsedSentence']=(' ').join(newTokens)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is treating each locationTokenID as a slot, when the locationTokenIDs really represent endpoints of a slice of tokens that should be treated as a slot. So we need to remove the `for locationTokenID in locationTokenIDs:` loop (which loops over each locationTokenID as if it were a slot), and replace the corresponding slice of words defined by the pair of locationTokenIDs with a single slot.

The following code solves the problem addressed in the OP, though other problems remain (such as only the last generated `slotSentence` is being retained; I will let you address this as I do not know what data structures you want to store the slot sentences in):

```
sample = "In the first 11 months of 2004 Hong Kong 's international airport at Chek Lap Kok handled daily an average of 592 flights , 92,630 passengers , and more than 7,734 tons of cargo."

tokenIDs2number = {(21,): 592, (24,): 92630,(30,): 7734}
tokenIDs2location = {(7,8): 'Hong Kong'}

for locationTokenIDs, location in tokenIDs2location.items():
    for numberTokenIDs, number in tokenIDs2number.items():    
        sentenceDict = {}    
        sentenceDict["sentence"] = sample    
        sentenceDict["location-value-pair"] = {location:number}  
        for numberTokenID in numberTokenIDs:                                   
            finalTokens = sample.split()
            finalTokens[numberTokenID] = "NUMBER_SLOT"
            finalTokens[locationTokenIDs[0]:(locationTokenIDs[1]+1)] = "LOCATION_SLOT"   
            slotSentence = (" ").join(finalTokens)
            sentenceDict["parsedSentence"] = slotSentence
            print(slotSentence)
```

**Output:**

> In the first 11 months of 2004 **L O C A T I O N _ S L O T** 's
>   international airport at Chek Lap Kok handled daily an average of
>   **NUMBER_SLOT** flights , 92,630 passengers , and more than 7,734 tons of
>   cargo.
>
> In the first 11 months of 2004 **L O C A T I O N _ S L O T**
>   's international airport at Chek Lap Kok handled daily an average of
>   592 flights , **NUMBER_SLOT** passengers , and more than 7,734 tons of
>   cargo.
>
> In the first 11 months of 2004 **L O C A T I O N _ S L O T**
>   's international airport at Chek Lap Kok handled daily an average of
>   592 flights , 92,630 passengers , and more than **NUMBER_SLOT** tons of
>   cargo.

This can be extended to work for locations and numbers containing any number of spaces. We implement this by having both numberTokenIDs and locationTokenIDs be a 2-length tuple specifying a range of tokens for each location/number:

```
sample = "In the first 11 months of 2004 Hong Kong Central 's international airport at Chek Lap Kok handled daily an average of 592 flights , 92 630 passengers , and more than 7 734 tons of cargo."

tokenIDs2number = {(22,22): '592', (25,26): '92 630',(32,33): '7 734'}
tokenIDs2location = {(7,9): 'Hong Kong Central'}

for locationTokenIDs, location in tokenIDs2location.items():
    for numberTokenIDs, number in tokenIDs2number.items():    
        finalTokens = sample.split()
        finalTokens[numberTokenIDs[0]:(numberTokenIDs[1]+1)] = "NUMBER_SLOT"
        finalTokens[locationTokenIDs[0]:(locationTokenIDs[1]+1)] = "LOCATION_SLOT"   
        slotSentence = (" ").join(finalTokens)
        print(slotSentence)
```

**Output:**

> In the first 11 months of 2004 **L O C A T I O N _ S L O T** 's
>   international airport at Chek Lap Kok handled daily an average of 592
>   flights , **N U M B E R _ S L O T** passengers , and more than 7 734 tons
>   of cargo.
>
> In the first 11 months of 2004 **L O C A T I O N _ S L O T** 's
>   international airport at Chek Lap Kok handled daily an average of 592
>   flights , 92 630 passengers , and more than **N U M B E R _ S L O T** tons
>   of cargo.
>
> In the first 11 months of 2004 **L O C A T I O N _ S L O T** 's
>   international airport at Chek Lap Kok handled daily an average of **N U
>   M B E R _ S L O T** flights , 92 630 passengers , and more than 7 734
>   tons of cargo.

Comment: this is a great answer and makes sense logically, can you explain why the location slots are being split up by whitespace? Also how can I make this generic (sometimes slots span more than just two spaces e.g. for countries like "Democratic Republic of Congo", and also there might be multiple slots for numbers too not just locations. Was playing around with using `len(locationTokenIDs)` but then I don't cover up the necessary countries.

Comment: This works as is for countries with any number of spaces since the values in locationTokenIDs represent slice endpoints and are treated as such in the code. The same logic that works for locations will also work for numbers. I updated my answer with code that works for locations and numbers with any number of spaces.

Comment: I just adapted your code but unfortunately this will not allow me to add multiple examples of the slot sentences in separate `sentenceDicts`. I also had to include an if statement e.g. `if len(numberTokenIDs)>1:
                            finalTokens[numberTokenIDs[0]:(numberTokenIDs[1]+1)] = "NUMBER_SLOT"
                        else:
                            finalTokens[numberTokenID] = "NUMBER_SLOT"`

Comment: The code generates all the slot sentences you were looking for, which is the issue you were asking for help with in the OP. You can do whatever you want with them once they are generated. Also, my solution requires changing the code that generates `tokenIDs2number` and `tokenIDs2location` such that the keys are **2-length tuples**  containing the start/end position of the location/number in the original sentence. If the country is only one word, for example, the key will look like `(i,i)`, where `i` is the location of the country name in the original sentence. This obviates your above `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `str.replace()` instead of splitting and slicing the sentence string. In order to so do, you need to convert the elements in `tokenID2number` with thousands separator which as @JonClements comments can be handled with `format(int, ',')` for Python 2.7+:

```
sample = "In the first 11 months of 2004 Hong Kong 's international airport " + \
         "at Chek Lap Kok handled daily an average of 592 flights " + \
         "92,630 passengers , and more than 7,734 tons of cargo."    
tokenIDs2number = {(22,): 592, (25,): 92630,(34,): 7734}
tokenIDs2location = {(8,9): 'Hong Kong'}

sentenceList = []
# ITERATE ACROSS A LIST COMPREHENSION FOR ALL POSSIBLE COMBINATIONS
for item in [[s,i,j] for s in [sample] \
                     for i in tokenIDs2location.items() \
                     for j in tokenIDs2number.items()]:
    sentenceDict = {}  
    sentenceDict["sentence"] = item[0]
    sentenceDict["location-value-pair"] = {item[1][1]: item[2][1]}
    sentenceDict["parsedSentence"] = sample.replace(item[1][1], 'LOCATION_SLOT').\
                                            replace(format(item[2][1], ','), 'NUMBER_SLOT')
    sentenceList.append(sentenceDict)
```

**Output** *(of sentenceList)*

```
[{'sentence': "In the first 11 months of 2004 Hong Kong 's international airport at Chek Lap Kok handled daily an average of 592 flights 92,630 passengers , and more than 7,734 tons of cargo.", 'parsedSentence': "In the first 11 months of 2004 LOCATION_SLOT 's international airport at Chek Lap Kok handled daily an average of 592 flights 92,630 passengers , and more than NUMBER_SLOT tons of cargo.", 'location-value-pair': {'Hong Kong': 7734}}
 {'sentence': "In the first 11 months of 2004 Hong Kong 's international airport at Chek Lap Kok handled daily an average of 592 flights 92,630 passengers , and more than 7,734 tons of cargo.", 'parsedSentence': "In the first 11 months of 2004 LOCATION_SLOT 's international airport at Chek Lap Kok handled daily an average of NUMBER_SLOT flights 92,630 passengers , and more than 7,734 tons of cargo.", 'location-value-pair': {'Hong Kong': 592}}
 {'sentence': "In the first 11 months of 2004 Hong Kong 's international airport at Chek Lap Kok handled daily an average of 592 flights 92,630 passengers , and more than 7,734 tons of cargo.", 'parsedSentence': "In the first 11 months of 2004 LOCATION_SLOT 's international airport at Chek Lap Kok handled daily an average of 592 flights NUMBER_SLOT passengers , and more than 7,734 tons of cargo.", 'location-value-pair': {'Hong Kong': 92630}}]
```

Comment: While it's great you credit Mike DeSimone for his recipe... for 2.7+ you can now write that as `format(int_value, ',')`...

Comment: @JonClements would this mean I can replace `replace(intWithCommas(item[2][1]), 'NUMBER_SLOT')` with `replace(format(item[2][1], ','), 'NUMBER_SLOT')` ?

Comment: @JonClements what happens if the tuple values are actually floats? Note these even look at values in the sentence like `24 million` and have converted these to `24000000.00`.

Comment: @JonClements - many thanks! Never knew that and we credit you now.

Comment: @DhruvGhulati, if values are floats, simply convert to `int()` or `round()` to nearest whole number before the `format(int, ',')`. And advise if this solution worked.

Comment: This is a great solution in concept but it requires me to understand what the original sentence format was for the float. This is not easy, and almost always gets things wrong e.g. `5500000.00` could be `5.5 million`, `0.55 billion`, `5500000`, or `5,500,000` among maybe 10 other combination. Trust me I tried!